# Javascript - Redirect Parameters URL Only Once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, redirect, userscripts

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TamperMonkey Redirect
// @include        http://tagpro-*.koalabeast.com:*
// @include        http://tangent.jukejuice.com:*
// @include        http://maptest*.newcompte.fr:*
// @version                1.0
// ==/UserScript==
window.location = window.location+'/?spectator=true';
```

That is the code i have so far. But /?spectator=true gets added forever, i want it to be added once.

/?spectator=true

(example: tagpro-123.koalabeast.com:8000/?spectator=true) to the URL ONLY ONCE? Thanks in advance.

Please note that this is not a duplicate, I tried the other link it did not work so please provide me with the full code and an explaination. Thank you very much!

Comment: i think im not seeing any actual code... maybe post some of that?

Comment: `if(window.location.indexOf('/?spectator=true') === -1)window.location = window.location+'/?spectator=true';`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (window.location.search != '?spectator=true') {
   window.location = window.location+'/?spectator=true';
}
```

Comment: hopefully he never tags another get variable to the end of the url

Comment: just answered the question.
to do more complicated things he should search here for 'javascript get params', there you find full answers galore

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED! YOU ROCK!